# Loading font option in fontspec

Tags: fonts, fontspec, opentype

I want to use the Alegreya Sans font in my document, so I installed the font on my computer, and use `fontspec` package to load it.

But I just can load several option like Algegreya Sans Light, Medium, etc (after compiling with XeLaTex, a pdf file is produced and I can view it properly). But when I change the option to Alegreya Sans alone, or Alegreya Sans Thin, etc then no pdf is produced and so I can't view pdf.

The font is installed properly and appeared in my Word processor.

So what is the problem?

Here is my MWE

```
 \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{memoir}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{total={14cm,21cm}}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \setmainfont{Alegreya Sans}
%\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
 \title{Linh Sơn}
 \author{Cao Hành Kiện}
 \begin{document}
 \maketitle
 \chapter{I}
 Tại sao compile mãi mà không ra gì cả? Why is there no pdf output?
 Tại sao Light, Medium được mà Thin không được? Why we can use Light, Medium, not Thin option?
 \end{document}
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` to your document and run your file on a terminal with `xelatex --no-pdf file` and then `xdvipdfmx -vv file.xdv` to get some info (in the log and in the terminal) what is wrong.

Comment: Interestingly enough, on TL2016 under Windows with those fonts installed I have no problem using your code with `lualatex`, but `xelatex` won't compile.

Comment: So what is the hidden problem here? I did install all Alegreya available fonts, but xelatex only work with Alegreya Sans Light/Medium, not thin, v.v